# Gnuplot: more than 2 datasets in single plot with 2 y-axes

Tags: plot, range, gnuplot, axes

I have multiple datasets I want to plot in a single figure:

```
plot "data1a.txt", "data1b.txt", "data1c.txt", "data2.txt"
```

I want to have two y-axes with different ranges.

```
yrange=[0:10]
y2range=[-10:10]
```

This is easily done on gnuplot if you only have two datasets. The first dataset uses `yrange` (with it's axis on the left hand side), and the second dataset uses `y2range` (with the axis on the right hand side).

Now here's the question. I want to plot datasets `data1a.txt`, `data1b.txt` and `data1c.txt` using `yrange`, and `data2.txt` using `y2range`. How do I do this on a single figure with two y-axes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As documented [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-10100034):

```
plot {<ranges>}  
      {<function> | {"<datafile>" {datafile-modifiers}}}  
      {axes <axes>} {<title-spec>} {with <style>}  
      {, {definitions,} <function> ...}
```

you can see that the `axes` are used in the plot command. After setting the ranges of your y-axes with

```
set yrange [y1min:y1max]
set y2range [y2min:y2max]
```

you can specify which axis you want to use in your plot with

```
plot "data.txt" axes x1y1
```

if you want to plot it against the first y-axis or

```
plot "data.txt" axes x1y2
```

if you want to plot it against the second y-axis.

Also see [this](http://folk.uio.no/hpl/scripting/doc/gnuplot/Kawano/plot1-e.html#5.2) example of how to use multiple axis in gnuplot.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work for a while then I realised I had to put the "using 1:2" part BEFORE the "axes x1y1" part. Thanks